# Sort Posts by most times viewed for WordPress Dashboard Widget

Tags: wordpress

I have looked around and unfortunately i am not able to find anything that helps me sort the most viewed posts in a dashboard widget. I am able to display the posts and how many times they have been viewed, but it looks like it is pulling and sorting by the most recent posts not the the times viewed.

Below is the code. Can anyone help me out?

```
// Adds view counter
function getCoupontViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "Used 0 Times";
    }
    return 'Used ' .$count. ' Times';
}

// Displays the view counter
function setCouponViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}       

function clipit_views_db() {
?>
    <ol>
        <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array( 
            'numberposts' => 5,
            'post_type' => 'coupon'
        );      
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php echo getCoupontViews(get_the_ID()); ?> </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php
}
function add_clipit_views_db() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'clipit_views_db', __( 'Recent ClipIt Views' ), 'clipit_views_db' );
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_clipit_views_db' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i was able to solve it by adding in additional information to get_posts()

```
function clipit_views_db() {
?>
    <ol>
        <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array( 
            'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
            'numberposts' => 5,
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => 'coupon'
        );          
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> <?php echo getCoupontViews(get_the_ID()); ?> </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php
}
function add_clipit_views_db() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget( 'clipit_views_db', __( 'Recent ClipIt Views' ), 'clipit_views_db' );
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_clipit_views_db' );
```